# Loop or DB query, Which one causes more time?

Tags: sql, database, performance, linq, loops

I have a table which has 8 column, but for a certain functionality I need only 4 column values out of the table. So I am currently selecting only the 4 column and mapping it to my entity and returning it. When I am mapping I believe there is a loop running on the retrieved value. So what is the best practice ? should I just retrieve all 8 values from DB or get only what I need and map it to entity and return it?

```
var users= (from u in context.Users
                             join r in base.DatabaseContext.Users 
                             where s.userId== id 
                             select new {
                                 Id=u.Id,
                                 FirstName=u.FirstName,
                                 LastName =u.LastName,
                                 IsActive=u.IsActive,
                              }).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(x => new WebCore.Model.User // Here i believe there will be an iteration on the retrieved result
                              {
                                  Id = x.Id,
                                  FirstName = x.FirstName,
                                  LastName = x.LastName,
                                  IsActive = x.IsActive,
                              }).AsQueryable();

return users;
```

My understanding is that IO operation causes the main performance issue. but at this scenario I am a bit confused. If possible please provide an detail explanation for me to understand the issue clearly.

Comment: As a very general answer, let the dbms do as much of the work as possible.

Comment: There's no IO operation (apart from pagefile if you haven't enough memory).

Comment: @jarlh so you prefer to retrieve all information from DB than doing this?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, you should only query the fields you need in your application.  Querying more fields than needed will result in an overhead reading these fields from these database and transporting the data over the network.  So in your case you should just query 4 columns, because that is what you need for now.

Regarding your concerns about your LINQ query, these queries are generally relatively efficient and I strongly advise against premature optimisation until it turns out to be a bottleneck. See Donald Knuth's opinion about this topic in my comment.

Comment: what is your conclusion? and what do you mean by "premature optimisation" ?

Comment: You should query 4 columns because that is what you need right now.

Comment: Regarding premature optimisation, Donald Knuth's wrote: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."